# Java generics bounds with recursive type parameters

Tags: java, generics, javac, java-7

I have a base class `Thing`, which provides some base functionality, including getting a reference to a `ThingInfo` with the type parameter of the type of the `Thing` sub class. Because Java does not have self types, I cannot use that for the type parameter to the `ThingInfo` return value, so `Thing` must take a recursive type parameter to allow us to return the correct parameterized `ThingInfo`.

```
interface ThingInfo<T>
{
    // just an example method showing that ThingInfo needs to know about
    // the type parameter T
    T getThing();
}

class Thing<T extends Thing<T>>
{
    // I need to be able to return a ThingInfo with the type parameter
    // of the sub class of Thing. ie. ThingA.getThingInfo() must return
    // a ThingInfo<ThingA>.
    // This is where Java would benefit from self types, as I could declare
    // the method something like: ThingInfo<THIS_TYPE> getThingInfo()
    // and Thing would not need a type parameter.
    ThingInfo<T> getThingInfo()
    {
        return something;
    }
}

// example Thing implementation
class ThingA extends Thing<ThingA>
{
}

// example Thing implementation
class ThingB extends Thing<ThingB>
{
}
```

So far everything is fine. This code works as needed.

I also need to represent a type safe relationship between `Thing`s.

```
class ThingRelation<X extends Thing<X>, Y extends Thing<Y>>
{
    X getParent()
    {
        return something;
    }

    Y getChild()
    {
        return something;
    }
}
```

Its not really that simple, but that demonstrates the need I think. Still, all of this is fine, no error yet. Now, `ThingRelation` needs method that takes an argument of a `ThingRelation` between `Y` and some other `Thing`. So I change `ThingRelation` to the following:

```
class ThingRelation<X extends Thing<X>, Y extends Thing<Y>>
{
    X getParent()
    {
        return something;
    }

    Y getChild()
    {
        return something;
    }

    <Z extends Thing<Z>> void useRelation(ThingRelation<Y, Z> relation)
    {
        // do something;
    }
}
```

But now I get this error when compiling it:

```
type argument Y is not within bounds of type-variable X
  where Y,X are type-variables:
    Y extends Thing<Y> declared in class ThingRelation
    X extends Thing<X> declared in class ThingRelation
```

The error is on the line starting `<Z extends Thing<Z>>....`

What on earth could be the problem?

*Update*: The `javac` version is `1.7.0_05`.

Comment: I get no errors with your exact code (using jdk1.6.0_20)

Comment: I don't get error as well with the code you posted

Comment: Sorry, I have also seen that this does work in Java 1.6.0_31. Seems only Java 7 has the error.

Comment: I suggest you review [Java SE 7 and JDK 7 Compatibility](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html). There are several notes on incompatibilities and/or errors in how generics are/were handled, and one of these might be applicable.

Comment: It looks like this was a bug in javac. It is compiles fine with jdk1.7.0_06, but I get the error from the question above in `java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)
`

Answer (score 0):

I get no errors with your exact code (using jdk1.6.0_20) .

Could it be that you have a shadowed type variable? You've obviously edited your example to simply your class names (`Thing` etc, which was good work btw), but maybe you've edited out more than you intended. Check your source code for declarations of `Y` and `X` types.

Comment: Sorry, see my update, in Java6 it seems to work. With Java 7 1.7.0_05 copy and paste from this question into outer class and compile fails.

Comment: I definitely get an error in jdk1.7.0_05, but not in jdk1.7.0_06. Looks like it was a javac bug. @herman: did you copy the second version of the `ThingRelation` class?

Comment: I think I did, yes.  Anyway, nice that it's working now in 1.7.0_06.